# Finding unique words in a specific text file and displaying a list of all the unique words found in the file python

Tags: python

Write a program that opens a specified text file and then displays a list of all the unique words found in the file.

*HINT: Store each word as an element of a set*

```
def main():
    # Open the text file
    text_file = open('for_exercise4.txt', 'r')
    read_file = text_file.readline()

    uniquewords = set([])
    print list(uniquewords)
```

This is what I've started with so far.
After this I would need to display the unique words in that text file using a set.

## EDIT

I've worked a little further into the exercise and this is what i came up with.

```
text_file = open(for_exercise4.txt, 'r')
read_file = text_file.read()
word_list = read_file.split()
uniquewords = set[(word_list])

for word in uniquewords:
    file.write(str(word) + "\n")
file.close()

print(uniquewords)
```

## EDIT #2

```
def main():
    file = open("c://users/Brandon/Desktop/PythonClass/for_exercise4.txt", 'r')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()

    uniquewords = []
    word_list = text.split()

    for word in word_list:
        if word not in uniquewords:
            uniquewords.append(word)
            print(str(word))
    file.close()

main()
```

When I run this it shows all the unique words but it doesn't store each word as an element of a set.

Comment: This doesn't show much effort. Stack Overflow is not a code writing resource. What methods have you tried to parse the words in the file? What else have you tried?

Comment: I'm still working on it now I just wanted to get my question out there to make sure I was on the right track.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done anything past the bare minimum of setting up the data structures. Come back when you've done some actual analytics on the file and I'd be glad to help you figure it out.

Comment: I've edited my code and when i run it i get the name 'for_exercise4' is not defined. Am i even on the right track @BadKarma

Comment: First of all `for_excercise4` has to be wrapped in quotes so it's parsed as a string not a variable. `"for_excercise4"`. And keep working, try checking the words in your word list.

Comment: Getting closer to a solution. I've edited my code some more. And actually getting the unique words in the text file. Is uniquewords = [] the correct way to store the words in a set?

Comment: Looks like you've put your time in. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well what you need to realize is that in a set you cannot have the same two items listed twice. That is one of the beautiful things about them. So all you really need to do is this.

```
text_file = open(for_exercise4.txt, 'r')
read_file = text_file.read()
word_list = read_file.split()
uniquewords = set(word_list)
```

Comment: Okay once I do this nothing shows up when I run it. when i have it at uniquewords = [] it runs but at uniquewords = set(word_list) it's blank.

Comment: Because you need to fill the word list first. Try looping over the file and reading the individual lines

Comment: Okay I'll work with that and see if i can get it. Thanks so much. Will let you know if I got it or not.